# Spatial joining two line layers and checking intersection in PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, intersection, st-intersects

I have two line layers in PostgreSQL/PostGIS. I want to the select data which are not intersecting. When I am writing this query it is taking a lot of time. How can I make it faster and see the result?

```sql
SELECT Geometry into Qlayer5
FROM qlayer4, egmap_20170316_tmc_polyline
WHERE st_intersects(qlayer59.Geometry,egmap_20170316_tmc_polyline.geom) = false
```

and I have also tried using right join but none of them giving output.

```sql
SELECT Geometry INTO Qlayer5
FROM qlayer4
RIGHT JOIN egmap_20170316_tmc_polyline ON
st_intersects(qlayer59.Geometry,egmap_20170316_tmc_polyline.geom) = false
```

Comment: non-intersections are tricky; your query will result in a carestian product of both tables, that's why it is so slow. your join condition matches **every pair of lines that do not intersect**; so if table A has 1 row and table B 100, with no intersection between them, you will get 100 rows returned!

Comment: ...or better, when table A has 3 rows and B 100, with no intersection, your query will return 300 rows. similar, with 1000 in A and 1000 in B, Postgres fetches 1000000 rows after computing each of them...

Comment: Ya understand but i dont find any other way to filter out non intersected lines.i am trying your queries now .Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: my suggestion is my answer. I'm just trying to explain why your query will fail with useless results after a lifetime of execution...,)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non-intersections are tricky. To avoid a cartesian product of the joined tables you need to either

- check against **a collection/union** of the joined tables' geometries:

  ```
  WITH
    col AS (
      SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
      FROM   egmap_20170316_tmc_polyline
    )
  SELECT *
  FROM   qlayer4 AS a
  JOIN   col AS b
    ON   NOT ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
  ;
  ```

  which will be **rather inefficient for larger tables** (indexes are less effective and the amount of vertices to traverse each time is extremely high)
- or **better, check against existence of intersections**:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM   qlayer4 AS a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   egmap_20170316_tmc_polyline AS b
    WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
  );
  ```

  which will at least use the index efficiently

Note that, even with the more optimized second query, this is a heavy operation and will likely take some time.

Comment: you genius. second query solved my problem almost

Answer (score 0):

Try this first for seeing the result of your query:

```
SELECT a.Geometry
FROM qlayer4 AS a,
egmap_20170316_tmc_polyline AS b  
WHERE
st_intersects(a.Geometry, b.geom) = false;
```

If it returns the expected result, insert the "INTO Qlayer5" statement.

Comment: Thank you @blabbath. This query i have tried earlier .it did not finish till two hours so, i stopped.

Comment: @poonampatel How many objects are in your tables? Have you set a spatial index?

Comment: yes i have set spatial index .i have quite a huge data.

Comment: Then, depending on your hardware specs and tuning parameters, 2 hours might just not be enough time.

Comment: I also think the same @blabbath. that is why i am looking for  efficient solution